# Force include a resource package in App Bundle for Windows Store Application ( Windows Phone 8.1)

Tags: windows-runtime, windows-phone, windows-phone-8.1, windows-rt

I have a windows phone application that currently supporting 2 Cultures( Arabic , English US ) with English US as  the default culture

i give the user the option to change the language from the application itself , but the problem is the application is packged as an App Bundle , and as long as the user didn't have Arabic in prefered languages the arabic app package is not downloded ( thus interface keep showing in english )

is there any way to mark more a resource package as mandatory or to set more than default resource package

Answer (score 0):

What about just not generate bundles?!

You can choose that, when you generate a package 
(Create AppBundle is by default: 'If Needed', you can change it to 'Never'.)